# Is it OK to have long running coroutines in FastAPI?

Tags: python, json, httprequest, python-asyncio, fastapi

Is it OK to have a 10-30 second coroutines in FastAPI?
(in the terms of FastApi performance and good practices)

So the client will have a request-response open for 10-30 seconds.
On the client side we are using React.js, so it's fine for them.

```py
@app.get("/somepath")
async def read_item():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        # some slow external API, 10-30 seconds
        async with session.get(f"https://external.website.com/{some_api_key}/") as response:
            response_json = await response.json()
            return response_json
```

Comment: ok in what terms ? performance ? user experience ?

Comment: in the terms of performance and good practices in FastAPI

Answer (score 1):

it will work. so no problem on this side.

UX) it makes perfectly sens for big jobs. no need to optimise too much if the user understand why he waits and has a clear response when the data is ready/fails.
you can implement a completion percentage if needed with socketio or sse (server sent events)

Perf) you can drastically reduce response time (hence performance and ux) by using caching. (if the call makes sens when cached)
it will reduce response time and reduce the number of concurent requests to the server.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can we be sure that keeping request-response open for 10-30 seconds is ok for FastApi in terms of it's performance? So if we have a lot of such coroutines, won't it hurt the performance of main thread?

Comment: you need to make a benchmark. that is the only way to mesure the impact for your use case. but it clearly works.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it OK to have a 10-30 second coroutines in FastAPI?

First of all, this is not a FastAPI question.

How many of these requests do you expect to have in parallel? Lots? Just a few? Do you want to limit how many coroutines you have running simultaneously? By default, asyncio will use as much resources as it possibly can. It might be what you want, it might not. If you want to limit how many coroutines can run at the same time and queue up requests, you might want to look at [asyncio.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore).

In regards to your question whether or not it's a good practice, it depends on your workflow. Asyncio was created especifically for this purpose, for long running background tasks to free up the application while they are doing their thing.

Now, if this is the best solution for your case, it's hard to tell without a clear picture of what your application is doing. What should happen if the user closes the browser while the request is still running in the server? The user wouldn't get a feedback about whether or not it completed successfully. Do you care about this scenario? If you do, you could consider using a queue and having a cronjob picking things up to process in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) on **how to properly make HTTP requests** within a FastAPI application, as well as how to **reuse** an `httpx.AsyncClient` connection (also knows as session), instead of creating a new session every time a client calls an endpoint.

**Code excerpt** (taken from the linked answers above):

```py
# ...
import httpx


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Initialise the Client on startup and add it to the state
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        yield {'client': client}
        # The Client closes on shutdown 


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get('/')
async def home(request: Request):
    client = request.state.client
    # ...
```

Moreover, if the response from the external API is quite large in size, you could **use a streaming response** instead of reading the response (JSON) data into memory, which could result in your machine running out of available RAM and slowing down (or even crashing) your application. Have look at the answers above on how to do that, as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75837557/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398460/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804).

You should also **considering caching/storing** the results returned from the external API (have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804) for more details), if they are not unique to a client and could be reused by others as well, so that you can avoid unecessary calls to that API, and hence, saving resources, maximising performance and minimising response time.

Further, **when dealing with returning JSON data** from a FastAPI backend, I would sugget having a look at the following answers, as they might help you optimising your code: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76206076/17865804), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173023/17865804). You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76122475/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77585366/17865804) helpful as well.

Finally, if you find the response taking too much time to be returned to the client, you may consider immediately replying to the user with a unique id, and then start **processing their request in the background**. Clients can then use that id to check on the status of their request (e.g., "Pending", "Processing" or Done"), and if the request is done processing, they could request the results (JSON data, in your case). Answers that follow a similar approach to this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77862153/17865804). You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73743908/17865804) helpful as well.